# Python 3. Объект списка, являющийся необязательным параметром функции, не удаляется после завершения работы функции

Tags: python, функции, список, параметры

---

Недавно начал изучать Python-3 и столкнулся с таким интересным поведением работы функций.

**Пример**:

```
def foo(x=[]):
    x.append(1)
    print x

foo()
foo()
foo()
```

**Результат**:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
```

То есть, объект списка не удаляется после завершения работы функции, как это происходит с другими объектами.

Причем, если список будет являться обязательным параметром функции, то, он, как и положено, будет удален по завершении работы функции.

Стало интересно, это баг или фича Питона? Буду благодарен за разъяснения. Погуглил, не нашел ответа на других ресурсах...

Comment: Вот, по первой же [ссылке](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/) в Гугле как раз ваш случай. 
 __A new list is created once when the function is defined, and the same list is used in each successive call.__  Т.е. список единожды создаётся на этапе декларирования функции и этот (один и тот же) список используется при каждом вызове.

Comment: Это не Python 3.